# Where is Trehavron, Kenwyn (Cornwall, England)?

Tags: cornwall, historical-gazetteer, 1830s

Today I received the Death Certificate of my 3rd great grandfather Henry Green whose death was registered in the District of Kenwyn (Cornwall, England).

It says fairly clearly that he died on 21 May 1839 at "Trehavron Kenwyn".

[image]

I have not been able to find Trehavron but I have found in [FamilySearch.org](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Kenwyn,_Cornwall_Genealogy) that:

> In Domesday Book the manor of Kenwyn appears as Tregavran (in later
>   usage Trehaverne).

Is it likely that the Trehavron where Henry (a Butcher) lived was the area around Tregavran/Trehaverne?

Comment: Not sure whether I'm worrying too much about your phrasing but don't confuse "manor" with "manor-house". Manor in this context is an area of land - presumably originally administered by a lord of the manor. So lots of people would live in that manor, in lots of houses.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianB38 - any efforts to improve my phrasing are appreciated. Mine here is certainly loose because I'm only vaguely familiar with manors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GENUKI's gazetteer entry for [Kenwyn](http://www.genuki.org.uk/node/75591) says:

> The parish of Kenwyn, (Cornish: Keynwynn), is situated in the Deanery and Hundred of Powder. It is bounded on the north by St Allen, on the east by St Clements, the parish of St Marys Truro and the river Fal, on the south by Kea, and on the west by St Agnes, the detached part of Kea called **Tregavethen**, and Perranzabuloe.

From British History Online's digital version of [Lewis' Topographical Dictionary](http://www.british-history.ac.uk/topographical-dict/england/pp386-390):

> **TREGAVETHAN**, a manor and extra-parochial district, in the parish of Kea, union of Truro, W. division of the hundred of Powder and of the county of Cornwall; containing 52 inhabitants. The manor comprises 1024 acres, of which 389 are common or waste land. It is situated on the borders of Kenwyn parish, and an aisle in that church is appropriated for its population. The impropriate tithes have been commuted for £70. 16. 8., and the vicarial for £22. 16. 8.

And from Wilson's Imperial Gazetteer at [A Vision of Britain](http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/place/1356), the entry on Kenwyn says, in part:

> The sub-district contains also the extra-parochial tract of **Tregavethan**.

Searching for Trehavron and for Tregavran/Trehaverne yielded no results.